# Installing python cgi in wamp apache on windows 7

Tags: python, apache, windows-7, wamp, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install mod_wsgi on windows 7, but can't get it to work. I've validated that everything is 32-bit, the filenames are correct and I've installed python 2.7 for all users. The python path has been added to PATH and I have checked it's working in console. Does anyone have any idea why apache produces the following message?

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 128 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.17/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.17/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The Apache service named is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: wouldn't mod_wsgi be a DLL on windows, not an so?

Comment: It follows Apache module convention of using a .so extension.

Comment: Yes, there are many .so modules. Only PHP uses a dll on my installation. And I'm pretty sure I downloaded the win32 extensions :)) I'm going to try and compile the extension myself, see if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Install/Re-install python for "All users". I faced the same problem.